# How to change my Laptop (Windows 10) login password from another pc

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop

I have lost my laptop and I want to change the windows 10 login password from another pc. As I remembered I was not using any microsoft account to sign in. Just that pc username and password.

Comment: Why do you want to do so? Even if you could, it could take effect only after it's connected to the internet. But to connect, somebody needs to login before. Also, even without the password the HDD can be just connected to another pc and the content copied.

Comment: Unless the content was encrypted, the new holder owns the data. Security & loss-prevention is something you need to do **before** you lose it.

Comment: You could conceivably use your second computer to create a bootable [Hiren's Boot](https://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) USB and use the Kon-Boot tool to bypass the password at login. Are you able to access your BIOS and change the boot order?

Answer (score 1):

Given the sparsity of detail in your question, at a guess, you most likely can't.

Resetting a password or doing other kinds of account management requires at least two things:

1. The computer you wish to manage (e. g. your stolen laptop) is connected to a network that you can access and you know the machine's IP address.
2. The computer is setup for some sort of remote management.

The first item is the most important. If the laptop is not connected to a network you can access (e.g it isn't connected to the internet or is behind network equipment that disallows certain types of communications), you're out of luck, period. But even this isn't enough. As stated, you also have to (at least in general terms) also know the IP address of the computer.

Even if you do get lucky with the network connection issues, the second item is just as important. The computer must have software or other features which allow remote management generally and more specifically remote commands that can influence user accounts. Likewise, the computer must be configured correctly for this type of management (e.g have the software or feature running and not be blocked by software firewalls).

If you do get a *new* laptop, there are plenty of ways to set it up to do what you are are asking, so I would highly recommend you do your research.

Assuming you want a simple anti-theft solution (again for a new laptop), [Prey](https://www.preyproject.com/pricing) has basic location, camera and device lock features even at it's free pricing level.

You may also wish to look into encryption for your files or hard disk if you are really worried about data theft since your laptop's hard drive can (potentially) be read directly even without logging in (via a secondary OS on removable media or by being connected to another computer).